# How to execute Julia statement that was generated dynamically

Tags: julia

In `Julia 1.4.2` language, I have generated a statement dynamically. What command should I use to execute it?

Example:

```
import Pkg; 
Pkg.add("DataFrames"); 
using DataFrames

i=1;  
e="df_original$i  = DataFrame(a = Int[], b = String[])"  
#i.e., the statement is "df_original1  = DataFrame(a = Int[], b = String[])"

Julia_exec(e)
```

What is the equivalent of `Julia_exec` in Julia that can execute the above statement?

Thanks

Comment: Please use the correct format for your post. You can read about the formatting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
eval(Meta.parse(e))
```

For your example:

```
julia> eval(Meta.parse(e));

julia> df_original1
0×2 DataFrame
```

More information can be found in Julia metaprogramming tutorial https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/

However, most tasks in Julia can be achieved without meta-programming and I strongly encourage you not to use it in normal workflows.

Comment: note that, unless this has changed in recent julia versions, it's worth mentioning that `eval` evaluates things at toplevel. i.e. this will probably cause problems if run inside a function

Comment: Yes, and you need for example `Base.invokelatest()` to handle that. There are many other issues too (such a hygiene for macros) and Julia is so powerful that for normal data science jobs one should not touch meta-programming at all.

Comment: Many thanks to both of you Przemyslaw Szufel and  Tasos Papastylianou-- appreciate it. I have noted your comments regarding metaprogramming.